# Difference between installing by pip and installing globally

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip, debian

I am workikng with Python/Django web application, in Amazon EC2 / Debian series operating system.

Application has Python setuptools library as dependency. So I installed setup this lib by this command globally:

> sudo apt-get install setuptools

But this didn't work - application says dependency didn't resolved correctly. After some googling, I have found solution, like this:

> pip install setuptools.

This worked for me.

But I have a question - what's difference between these two? Of course, I didn't activated virtualenv, so it seems setuptools is installed globally.

Would you like to bring me your experience? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are 2 separate package managers, that sometimes don't play well with each other.

```
# linux system level as root
(sudo) apt-get install

# inside of an more isolated python folder structure, that does not interface with the system level packages
(venv) pip install
```

You may* be able to install with all of the build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential 
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install setuptools` this is too different from  `pip install setuptools.`

[Sudo apt-get install](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html) is use to install packages from Linux repository, and pip is for install libraries or packages for python. If you use virtual environments you install different libraries for each project [read more about it here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).